# How to manipulate an SVG element

Tags: html, sass, chart.js, chartist.js

Just found out that what I am trying to change is called an SVG Element. Hopefully that helps clear the question.

I have a bar graph on my application and I want to change the Sass of the bars within the graph. Inspecting the HTML within the browser I am able to see that you can make these adjustments by changing the x and y values below. Where/how can I change these values in my actual code to reflect the changed in my application? I have tried to look up the issue online but am not sure how to word the problem.

```
<svg>
<g class="ct-series ct-series-a">
    <line 
    x1="197.5" 
    x2="197.5" 
    y1="45" 
    y2="5" 
    class="ct-bar" 
    ct:value="1" 
    style="stroke: orange">

    </line>
</g>
</svg>
```

I have checked in my HTML, SCSS, and TS pages but am not able to find any elements that look like they can be manipulated. I have attached all of my scss references to my chartist graph below. And help would be greatly appreciated.

```
.ct-chart {
    .ct-series-a .ct-line {
        stroke: #253B56;
        stroke-width: 1px;
    }

    .ct-series-a .ct-point {
        stroke: darkblue;
        stroke-width: 5px;
    }

    .ct-series-a .ct-bar {
        stroke: gray;
        stroke-width: 34px;
        stroke-linecap: square;

    }

    .ct-series-b .ct-bar {
        stroke: gray;
        stroke-width: 30px;
        stroke-linecap: square;
    }

    .ct-series-c .ct-bar {
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 30px;
        stroke-linecap: square;
    }
}
```

and lastly

```
new Chartist.Bar(ident, data2, options2)
              .on('draw', function(data) {
                for(var index in data.series){
                  if(data.series[index] == 1 && data.index == index){
                    data.element.attr({
                      style: 'stroke: orange'
                      // line x1="162.5", 
                      // x2="162.5", 
                      // y1="15", 
                      // y2="5,"
                    });
                  }
                }
              });
          }
```